# Implement layout tag for liquid template engine

Tags: ruby, liquid

I want to themed my blog that use liquid template engine, but default, the engine only support some basic tags, I want to write custom tag {% layout 'layout_name' %}

Layout file: dark.liquid

```
<html>
...
{% content_for_body %}
...
</html>
```

And template file: blog.liquid

```
{% layout 'dark' %}
welcome to my blog!
```

And output

```
<html>
...
welcome to my blog!
...
</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that something like this is possibly except for grabbing the first line and extracting the layout name before passing the rest of `blog.liquid` in, for example:

```
post = "{{ layout 'dark' }}\nWelcome to my blog!"

layout_name = post.split("\n").first.match(/\{\{ layout '(.+)' \}\}/)[1]
#=> "dark"
content = post.split("\n")[1..-1].join("\n")
#=> "Welcome to my blog!"
```

Also it should be "{{ content_for_body }}"; "{% ... %}" is used for tag blocks like an if statement.

Comment: @hawx, i really don't understand your solution. Can you explain me further?